# Python + Selenium. Как найти CSS для таблицы подсказок в Яндксе?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]как нати CSS у таблицы подсказок на https://yandex.ru/. Поиск по подчеркнутому CSS не работает (.mini-suggest__popup.mini-suggest__popup_svg_yes.mini-suggest__popup_theme_flat.mini-suggest__popup_visible)

```
....
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
try:
    suggest = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.mini-suggest__item')
except NoSuchElementException: #проверяем есть ли таблица с подсказками
    print('Нет таблицы с подсказками')
```

Comment: Вы хотите находить значения из этого списка? Можете так если ищите через селектор .mini-suggest__popup-content > li

Comment: Я хочу просто проверить, что он действительно выпадает :) 
Я ввожу что-нибудь, и выпадающий список есть. Значения меня пока что не интересуют. Но большое спасибо за комментарий!

Comment: Тогда можете также искать li и если он не найден значит подсказок нет = список не выпадает. Ещё когда список выпадает там динамически появляется класс mini-suggest__popup_visible, по нему думаю тоже можно попробовать искать.

Comment: Я тоже подумал про mini-suggest__popup_visible, но вот пока не могу сообразить как это написать в коде.  По этому селектору он его не находит почему-то в html

Comment: .mini-suggest__popup-content > li, через этот CSS не получится. Он присутствует даже если самой таблицы подсказок нет

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutExcept
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver

try:
    popup = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.mini-suggest__popup.mini-suggest__popup_theme_flat.mini-suggest__popup_visible')))

except TimeoutException: #проверяем есть ли таблица с подсказками
        print('Нет таблицы с подсказками')
```

И все сработало)
Вот: EC.visibility_of_element_located

Comment: Этот комментарий можно удалить